# r2dbc-pool can do validationInterval?

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-mysql

Is there a way to permanently activate the connection pool by performing validation queries at regular intervals?

Or is there any way to recreate when reached maxIdleTime? (Not just evict)

I've looked up a lot of documents, but I haven't found options like validationInterval.
https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-pool